# How to record a FaceTime call on OS X?

Tags: macos, facetime

How can I record a FaceTime call and save the video on my Mac?

<sup>I am using a MacBook Air 11" with OS X 10.8.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facetime does not include this functionality directly.

One of the possibilities you have is using [QuickTime X's screen recording](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5882) feature.

Comment: That's a little complicated, Sir

Comment: Why do you say it is complicated?  Are you talking about the sound

Comment: @markhunte I am talking about the video.

Comment: This feature quite easy to use imho.

Comment: It is not complicated to set up. But I meant also recording the sound. Which could be a little bit fiddly the first time and may require a third party app. Or you looping a cable from you headphone jack to your mic jack.

Comment: There's finally an app for this! Call Recorder for FaceTime is a Mac app that was just released today:

https://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorderft/

Answer (score 1):

There's finally an app for this! Call Recorder for FaceTime is a Mac app that was just released today:

https://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorderft/

This product is a plug-in that adds recording controls to the FaceTime app. Recording can be started manually, or it can be configured to record automatically. It creates internet-ready QuickTime movies. 
Another great use is recording phone calls that come through the Mac via Yosemite's new Handoff feature.

(full disclosure: I work on this product!)

Comment: Would you like to disclose some features rather than just a link and also that you're part of the company ecamm ? :)

Comment: yes, i will. edited!